# Dask str.findall(pattern) returns series of type string, but it should be object

Tags: dask

After dask update, the method str.findall(regex) returns dask series of type string instead of a object

example:

```
s = pd.Series(['some sentence 1' 'some other sentence 2', 'some other sentece 3', 'some other sentece 4'])
ds = dd.from_pandas(s, npartitions = 2)
pattern = r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\b'
ds2 = ds.str.findall(pattern) # this should be of type object where each item is a list, but its of type string like "['some', 'sentence']"
ps = ds2.compute()
type(ps[0]) # this should be a list, but its a string
```

I have dask 2023.7.1 using the latest jupyter/datascience-notebook docker image

[image: dask issue]

Comment: I cannot confirm - I get a `list`

Comment: thank you for trying to help....did you try the same dask version?

Comment: 2023.8.0, almost